# how to save Gridview Data in asp.net using ado.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to save my GridView data to a database using a `foreach` loop.
but the program is not entering the loop.

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    foreach (GridViewRow row in grdYarnIssue.Rows) {
        tbl_YarnIssueTemp item2 = new tbl_YarnIssueTemp();

        item2.LotNo = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[2].Text.Trim());
        item2.Unit = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[3].Text);
        item2.IssueQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[4].Text);
        item2.Rate = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[].Text);

        dbcontext.tbl_YarnIssueTemp.AddObject(item2);
        dbcontext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you use debugger to see why `grdYarnIssue.Rows` is probably equal to 0 ?

Comment: yep...debugger is't entering the loop..

Comment: rebuild application and then try with debugger , as enter in loop